# Printing multiple lines with the same "largest" value using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
3, abc, x
2, def, y
3, ghi, z
```

I want to find the highest value in `$1` and print all rows that contain this highest value in `$1`.

```
sort -t, -k1,1n| tail -n1
```

would just give one of the rows that contain 3 in `$1`, but I need both.

Any suggestions are appreciated (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if this is the nicest way to get lines while they have the same value with awk, but:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { t = $1; print } NR > 1 { if (t != $1) { exit; } print }'
```

which can be combined with `sort` as follows:

```
sort -t, -k1,1nr | awk 'NR == 1 { t = $1; print } NR > 1 { if (t != $1) { exit; } print }'
```

There’s also this, but it does unnecessary work:

```
sort -t, -k1,1nr | awk 'NR == 1 { t = $1 } t == $1 { print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that does not require sorting, but requires two passes over the data.

```
max=$(awk -F',' '{if(max < $1) max = $1}END{print max}' Input.txt )
awk -v max=$max -F',' '$1 == max' Input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk, only one pass over the data:

```
$ awk -F, '
$1>m {                   # when new max is found
    delete a; m=$1; i=0  # reset all
}
a[1]=="" || $1==m {      # if $1 equals max or we're processing the first record
    a[++i]=$0            # store the record to a 
}         
END {                    # in the end
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) 
        print a[j]       # print a with stored records
}     
' file
3, abc, x
3, ghi, z
```